# How to return VBS variable to Python?

Tags: python, vbscript

I want to open up a VBScript `InputBox` in Python, and then return a variable to Python to use. In my Python file I have:

```python
os.system("SAVE.vbs")
```

and in my VBScript file I have:

```vb
Dim savename
savename = InputBox("Name to save file as: ", "Save File")
```

How would I go about returning the `savename` variable into my python file?

Comment: Have the VB script print the filename, and run it from Python using `subprocess.check_output`? Or just use a Python GUI toolkit instead...

Comment: @kindall How would I have the VBScript print the filename to use? Say if I wanted it to be `name=subprocess.check_output`

Comment: `WScript.StdOut.WriteLine savename` or `WScript.Echo savename`. You MUST run the VBScript with `cscript.exe` for either to work.